# UPDATE (SELECT ... ) SET ...

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, sql-update

I would like to update the results of a table that is returned via a SELECT statement.

So I want to:

```
UPDATE (SELECT [a bunch of joins etc.]) SET thisRecord = 1 WHERE [blah blah]
```

this doesn't seem to work at all for me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't update the results of a SELECT statement. You have to update a table or set of tables. One thing that you can do, though, is UPDATE with an INNER JOIN, like this: `UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field2 SET table1.field3 = 'some value' ... etc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET column1 = t2.Column
FROM  table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT ... FROM ... lots of joins etc) t2
ON t1.id = t2.otherid
```

Comment: I've read this solution before; however, I want my 'Table1' table be the (SELECT ...) stuff.

Comment: Edited... this any better?

Comment: Thanks Paul .. that's exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question well, this is what you will want to do:

```
UPDATE your table name SET thisRecord = 1
WHERE your_criteria = (SELECT [a bunch of joins etc.])
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) says it all. You can not do as you are thinking.
What you can do, however, is to translate your inner select

```
SELECT [a bunch of joins etc.]
```

to a condition applied on the table to update.